# Linq to Entities selecting properties from related objects

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, orm, properties, linq-to-entities

I have several tables that are properly linked and mapped through FKs / link tables.

ie: *link_table -> 1 to many relationship to table_one and table_two -> many to many relationship to table_three*

```
var results = db.link_table.Where(l => l.table_one.RandomProperty == "value");
```

The above obviously works but I want to be able to make a select like this:

```
var results = db.link_table.Where(l => l.table_one.RandomProperty == "value" && l.table_two.table_three.RandomProperty == "anothervalue");
```

This fails because it seems not possible to access the properties that belong to table_three. The SQL query I would like should resemble something like this (the WHERE part is the most important):

```
SELECT * FROM link_table
LEFT JOIN table_one ON table_one.assoc = link_table.assoc
LEFT JOIN table_two ON table_two.assoc = link_table.assoc
LEFT JOIN table_three ON table_two.assoc = table_three.assoc
WHERE table_one.RandomProperty = "value" AND table_three.RandomProperty = "AnotherValue"
```

How would I be able to access the "RandomProperty" of table_three through the relational mapping of Linq2Entities? Is it even possible in one single line of code and thus getting the result I want in one automatically generated SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The in-depth answer is given to this question: [linq to entities, a where in where clause? (inner where)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258838/linq-to-entities-a-where-in-where-clause-inner-where). It involves using the `.Any()` command to search through the related many-to-many table data.

i.e.:

```
var results = db.link_table.Where(l => l.table_one.RandomProperty == "value" && l.table_two.table_three.Any(t => t.RandomProperty == "value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare all your FK properties as virtual in all model classes.
And then use this code:-

```
var results = db.link_table.Where(l => l.table_one.RandomProperty == "value" && l.table_two.table_three.RandomProperty == "value").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: could you perhaps elaborate on how I can set the FK's to virtual? Is it possible to do so from the L2E Designer interface or does it require manual editing of the generated code file?

Comment: try setting navigation properties in the generated code files as virtual like `public virtual ICollection<Product> Products` . If that doesn't make the code work than just use the include statement in above code

Comment: I declared everything in navigation properties of the models to virtual and tried the Include but the table_three properties still won't show up nor will the code compile. Is there another workaround you know of, assuming my relational mapping might not be properly set-up and L2E therefore won't accomplish this seemingly easy task?

Comment: Remove the virtual from navigation properties and try this `var results = db.link_table.Include("table_one").Include("table_two").Where(l => l.table_one.RandomProperty == "value" && l.table_two.table_three.RandomProperty == "value").FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: The name of the navigation property will come between the double quotes like this : "*yourNavigationProperty*" ...

Comment: Using the Includes still didn't give me access to the properties of table_three - I tried it the way you specified and in several variations. The following method appears to work but obviously isn't how I can properly select the value I really want: db.link_table.Where(l => l.table_one.RandomProperty == "value" && l.table_two.table_three.FirstOrDefault().RandomProperty == "value").FirstOrDefault();