# linq to entities, a where in where clause? (inner where)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities

I have a table with a one to many mapping to a table that has a many to many mapping to another table. I'd like to do the following:

```
var results = context.main_link_table
                     .Where(l => l.some_table.RandomProperty == "myValue" &&
                            l.some_table.many_to_many_table
                             .Where(m => m.RandomProperty == "myValue"));
```

How can I achieve this? The first part will work but when trying it without the 'inner WHERE', I can't access the many_to_many_table's properties, but the "inner where" obviously won't compile. I basically want to achieve something like the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * from main_link_table
INNER JOIN some_table AS t1 ON t1.association = main_link_table.association
INNER JOIN many_to_many_table AS t2 ON t2.association = some_table.association
WHERE t1.RandomProperty = 'MyValue' AND t2.RandomProperty = 'MyValue'
```

It's seemingly simple but I can't find a way to achieve it in one single line of linq - using multiple lines to achieve the desired effect returns too much results and I end up having to loop through them. I also tried stuff like:

```
var results = main_link_tbl.Include("some_table.many_to_many_table")
                           .Where(l => l.some_table.many_to_many_table.<property>
                                       == "MyValue")
```

But at this point I can't select a property of many_to_many_table unless I add a FirstOrDefault(), which nullifies the effect since it won't search through all the records.

What did work, but requires multiple lines of code and in the background returns too many results in the SQL query built by the linq-to-entities framework:

```
var results = db.main_link_table.Include("some_table")
                                .Include("some_table.many_to_many_table")
                                .Where(s => s.some_table.RandomProperty 
                                            == "myValue")
                                .Select(s => s.some_table);

foreach(var result in results) {
    var match_data = result.Where(s => s.many_to_many_table.RandomProperty
                                       == "myValue");
}
```

This piece of code will return all rows inside some_table that match the first Where condition and then applies the next Where condition, while I obviously only need a single row where the many_to_many_table.RandomProperty equals myValue.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It should work if you change the inner `Where` to `Any`:

```
var results = context.main_link_table
                     .Where(l => l.some_table.RandomProperty == "myValue" &&
                                 l.some_table.many_to_many_table
                                  .Any(m => m.RandomProperty == "myValue"));
```

Comment: The only issue with using ANY on the Many side is that it's not a true WHERE clause, it's only detecting whether there are any records that satisfy the condition.  For example. if you had ANY  many.balance > 0 that would return true if at least 1 record had a balance greater than 0.  So it wouldn't filter out those records with a balance of 0. Remember, ANY merely returns a Boolean to indicate the existence of records, it doesn't actually filter.

Comment: @CharlesOwen And a boolean is EXACTLY what we need here, because we are using the `Any` as a condition inside a `Where`.

Comment: Well, kind sir, I brought up a different scenario where it doesn't work.  And Jon Skeet's answer is the better solution overall because it allows finer granular control if you had several nested levels of joins.It may have resolved that very simple question asked, but normally queries aren't so simple.  I've dealt with queries joining 7 or more tables with LEFT JOIN's etc.  Your solution won't work for that.

Comment: @CharlesOwen: You only need a `Where` instead of `Any`, if you actually need to access the data in the joined table(s). In that case, you will most definitely need a join as Jon pointed out. If you are only using the joined tables as a filter - as was the case here - then `Any" suffices. Any can be nested just as well. Hope this clears things up a bit.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do a join, why don't you just do a join?

```
var query = from main in context.MainLinks
            join t1 in context.Some on main.Association equals t1.Association
            where t1.RandomProperty == "MyValue"
            join t2 in context.ManyToMany on t1.Association equals t2.Association
            where t2.RandomProperty == "MyValue"
            select new { main, t1, t2 };
```

That should achieve exactly what your SQL does...

Comment: I would argue that this is a better solution than the selected answer because it demonstrates a true where clause allowing you to filter out those records in the many table you don't want.

Answer (score 2):

```
from link in db.main_link_table
join s in db.some_table on link.association1 = s.association
join m in db.many_to_many_table on link.association2 = m.association
where s.X = 'MyValue' AND m.Y = 'MyValue'
select m; // or s or link or both 3 as you want
```